Observable Notebook VS code Extension fetch error Observable JS Gordon Smith
Trying to analyse several website content using ObservableHQ Notebook(Observable JS
Gordon Smith) running on my laptop in VS code Windows 10 OS.
here is the code line in a cell which is perfectly working when i download something like https:site/file.json
{
    return fetch('https://google.com/').catch(e => e)
}

but when I want to parse html It return the error:

TypeError: Failed to fetch at eval (eval at createFunction (https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/c%3A/Users/yugin/.vscode/extensions/gordonsmith.observable-js-0.4.37/dist/ojsRenderer.js:6659:12), :4:12) at https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/c%3A/Users/yugin/.vscode/extensions/gordonsmith.observable-js-0.4.37/dist/ojsRenderer.js:11499:61 at new Promise () at variable_compute (https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/c%3A/Users/yugin/.vscode/extensions/gordonsmith.observable-js-0.4.37/dist/ojsRenderer.js:11499:9) at Runtime.runtime_computeNow (https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/c%3A/Users/yugin/.vscode/extensions/gordonsmith.observable-js-0.4.37/dist/ojsRenderer.js:11410:7) at https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/c%3A/Users/yugin/.vscode/extensions/gordonsmith.observable-js-0.4.37/dist/ojsRenderer.js:11347:74

I expecting that fetch() function return HTML or Text content
